# AjaxControlToolKit AjaxFileUpload, upload files without an extension

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

Using the AjaxControlToolKit AjaxFileUpload control (v18.1.1), how can I allow files without an extension to be uploaded? 
Currently, any file without an extension throws an error. I know there is a default whitelist and the ability to add allowed extensions in the web.config, but it's not clear how to allow files without an extension.

Answer (score 1):

As of v18.1.1, the AjaxFileUpload does not allow uploading of files without an extension in its current state.